# UTM convertor from one zone to next zone

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I want to convert the UTM coordinate system WGS 84  "E,N " from 38 N ZONE to 39 N or to 37 N.

Please send me the formula and programs that I can do it.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum.Please go through http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

PROJ 4. QGIS, GDAL and  PostGIS are one of programs which use it. Get QGIS ( i assume that you use compatible data format) Figure out your source and target SRID and do re-projection.

that's all i can do with current information. In future you could add litlle more information like file format because it can cause problems

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to convert from one zone to another, If you have your data in shapefile, using ArcGIS you can very easily do this.
Go to ArcToolbox-> Data Management tools-> Projections and transformations-> Feature toolset > Project. & there you are.
[ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Project/00170000007m000000/) for Project tool.